# Would this perform better with LINQ?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, datatable

Below method selects admin rights and returns bool from a cached DataTable, would it perform better with Linq?

You might ask why don't you test it. Well,due to lack of knowledge i can't write it in Linq

```
 DataRow[] result = PrivilegeMap.Select("privilegeActionId=" + (int)actionId);
            bool moderatorHasIt = Convert.ToBoolean(result[0]["moderatorHasIt"]);
            bool adminHasIt = Convert.ToBoolean(result[0]["adminHasIt"]);                                        
            if (myRole == User.Role.Admin)
            {
                return Convert.ToBoolean(adminHasIt);
            }
            if (myRole == User.Role.Moderator)
            {
                return Convert.ToBoolean(moderatorHasIt);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because I remembered that DataTable maintains indices based on `Select` queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably would be faster using LINQ because the datatable wouldn't have to parse your query string, but you'll get the greatest advantage by changing the data representation to avoid querying against a datatable in the first place.

Create an `IDictionary<int, bool>` that represents the privileges you're interested in, keyed by `actionId`. Then when you need to do a lookup, you can just return `dict[actionId`.

Regardless, I suspect this is probably a case of *Premature Optimization*: have you tested your program and found that this piece of code represents a significant portion of your processing time?

Comment: Thanks, and no it will only be called by few users. I just wanted to know if linq would make big difference

Comment: @nLL: Then your time is best used elsewhere. :-)

Comment: The database is going to have to parse *something* whether it comes from Linq, Datatable, or hand-codes SQL.

Comment: @JonHanna: Assuming the DataTable is in memory (the OP said it's a *cached* datatable), you can iterate across the rows programmatically without going to the database. In that case, LINQ to Objects wouldn't need to *parse* the query so much as *run* it.

Comment: Right you are, I missed the word "cached" above, so while I mentioned the possibility in my answer, I then wrote as if it wasn't the case.

Answer (score 2):

It *could* be.

Let's assume the following:

1. The balance of starting size, read frequency and update frequency of the underlying table is such that it doesn't make sense to replace the whole thing with loading it all into memory and just repeatedly looking at that.
2. There's only one matching row for each id.
3. There's a bunch of other interesting fields in the row, that we don't care about here.

Then if we replaced PrivilegeMap with a Linq2SQL `Table<Privileges>`, the equivalent LINQ code is going to be something like:

```
var result = PrivilegeMap.Where(p => p.PrivilegeActionId == actionID).Select(p => new{p.ModeratorHasIt, p.AdminHasIt}).First()
if (myRole == User.Role.Admin)
{
  return result.AdminHasIt;
}
if (myRole == User.Role.Moderator)
{
  return result.ModeratorHasIt;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

(For that matter `var result = PrivilegeMap.Where(p => p.PrivilegeActionId == actionID).First(p => new{p.ModeratorHasIt, p.AdminHasIt})` can also be written as `var result = (from p in PrivilegeMap where p.PrivilegeActionId == actionID select new{p.ModeratorHasIt, p.AdminHasIt}).First()` It's just a different syntax for the same LINQ operations).

Lets say `actionID` is `2`
Your code will be turned into SQL along the lines of:

SELECT * FROM Privileges WHERE privilegeActionId=2

The Linq above would be turned into:

SELECT TOP 1 adminHasIt, moderatorHasIt FROM Privileges WHERE privilegeActionId

You can see how, if this were a table with lots of columns and/or if there was more than one matching row, this could be much more efficient.

(If PrivilegeMap was enumerable but not queryable it would turn into an operation where the whole thing was loaded and scanned, and hence not efficent at all).

On the other hand though, the code to produce that SQL could be more complicated, and it requires some work in setting up the privilege entity objects. If this were a one-off operation it certainly wouldn't be worth it in terms of either developer or runtime efficiency, but otherwise it could benefit both.

However, note that in both our cases we're querying needlessly. I'd actually replace mine with:

```
if (myRole == User.Role.Admin)
{
  return PrivilegeMap.Where(p => p.PrivilegeActionId == actionID).Select(p => p.AdminHasIt).First();
}
if (myRole == User.Role.Moderator)
{
  return PrivilegeMap.Where(p => p.PrivilegeActionId == actionID).Select(p => p.ModeratorHasIt);
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

Which will either query for just adminHasIt, just moderatorHasIt, or **not query at all since we're guaranteed false for any other value of `myRole` no matter what the database state**.

Likewise, you get a much simpler improvement with:

```
if(myRole != User.Role.Admin && myRole != User.Role.Moderator)
  return false;
DataRow[] result = PrivilegeMap.Select("privilegeActionId=" + (int)actionId);
if (myRole == User.Role.Admin)
{
  return Convert.ToBoolean(result[0]["adminHasIt"]);
}
if (myRole == User.Role.Moderator)
{
  return Convert.ToBoolean(result[0]["moderatorHasIt"]);
}
```

Here we first avoid the database query entirely if we can't possibly use it, only convert the field we care about, and don't subsequently convert a bool to a bool. This sort of local thinking about what data is actually used is much easier to do and while most such savings are small, some are big (this one could potentially be) and they're a matter of habit rather than complicated trade-offs.

Comment: You're welcome, though I only now see that your question said the table was cached. In this case you'd be faster with the suggestion @StriplingWarrior made, of using a Dictionary instead. That said, you could of course be querying the same table (whether a cached DataTable or a List<Privilige> for Linq2Objects) for other things, which changes the balance yet again. In the latter case, the performance between linq and your approach is a lot closer.

Answer (score 1):

The code you listed is not complete, as the `myRole` variable is not defined.

With that in mind, I would suggest writing it in a switch statement and move on till it is identified as a problem. Plus it would be easier to read (in my opinion).